# Shiny App with Plotly graph

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I am new to shiny and plotly!

I am trying to develop a Shiny app using plotly for graph.

My App folder looks like:

- www -> plotlyGraphwidget.js
- global.R
- plotlyGraphwidget.R
- ui.R
- server.R

plotlyGraphwidget.js has the javascript i got from the plotly blogs.

global.R is having the username and apikey, i got from registering on plotly.

plotlyGraphwidget.R has the interface function between ui.R and server.R

ui.R has the ui elements definition.

server.R has the data manpulation and the renderGraph functionality.

In renferGraph, I am using following approaches for ploting plotly:

- using ggplot2 and then converting it into plotly using gg2list()
- directly using ggplotly()

I am able to get the plotly graph but the graph is not getting populated on the app.

```
ui.R

shinyUI(navbarPage("Hello",
                   tabPanel("ABC",
                            shinyUI(fluidPage(

                              # Application title
                              titlePanel("ABC1"),

                              # Sidebar with a input for the number of bins
                              helpText("Help me"),
                              helpText("Help Me"),
                              fluidRow(
                                column(6,uiOutput("Box10")),
                                column(6,uiOutput("Box1")),
                                column(6,uiOutput("Box2")),
                                column(6,uiOutput("Box3")),
                                column(6,uiOutput("Box4"))
                              ),


                              mainPanel(
                                    graphOutput('trendPlot')                                                             
                              )

                            )
                            )) 

))
```

server.R

```
library(ggplot2);
library(shiny);
library(reshape2);


##Read data##
test=read.csv("data.csv",header = TRUE);
test$Price=as.numeric(as.character(test$Price));

if (nrow(test[is.na(test$Price)==TRUE,])>0) {
  test[is.na(test$Price)==TRUE,]$Price=0;  
};

if (nrow(test[test$Price <0,])>0) {
  test[test$Price <0,]$Price = 0;
};

names(test)[1]="Territory_1";
test1=test[test$Territory_1=='National',];
territory_list=unique(test$Territory_1);
territory_list=territory_list[territory_list!='National'];
combinations=test[1,];
combinations=combinations[-1,];

if (length(territory_list)!=0) {

  for (i in 1:length(territory_list))
  {
    territory=territory_list[i];
    tmp=test[test$Territory_1==territory,];
    tmp=rbind(tmp,test1);
    Seller=unique(tmp$Seller);
    sample=unique(tmp[,c("Territory_1","Category","Sub_category","flag","price_point","IA_Category","Date")]);
    sample$a=1;
    Seller=as.data.frame(Seller);
    Seller$a=1;
    sample=merge(x = sample,y = Seller,by.x="a",by.y="a",all=TRUE);
    sample=sample[,-1];
    rm(Seller);
    sample=merge(x = sample,y=tmp,
                 by.x = c("Category","Sub_category","flag","price_point","IA_Category","Seller","Territory_1","Date"),
                 by.y = c("Category","Sub_category","flag","price_point","IA_Category","Seller","Territory_1","Date"),
                 all.x=TRUE);
    sample[is.na(sample$Price)==TRUE,]$Price=0.0;
    sample=sample[,c("Territory_1","Category","Sub_category","flag","price_point","Seller","Price","Date","IA_Category")];
    combinations=rbind(combinations,sample);
    rm(sample,tmp,territory);
  };
  rm(i,territory_list,test,test1);
  test= combinations;
  rm(combinations);
} else if (length(territory_list)==0) {

  tmp=test;
  Seller=unique(tmp$Seller);
  sample=unique(tmp[,c("Territory_1","Category","Sub_category","flag","price_point","IA_Category","Date")]);
  sample$a=1;
  Seller=as.data.frame(Seller);
  Seller$a=1;
  sample=merge(x = sample,y = Seller,by.x="a",by.y="a",all=TRUE);
  sample=sample[,-1];
  rm(Seller);
  sample=merge(x = sample,y=tmp,
               by.x = c("Category","Sub_category","flag","price_point","IA_Category","Seller","Territory_1","Date"),
               by.y = c("Category","Sub_category","flag","price_point","IA_Category","Seller","Territory_1","Date"),
               all.x=TRUE);
  sample[is.na(sample$Price)==TRUE,]$Price=0.0;
  sample=sample[,c("Territory_1","Category","Sub_category","flag","price_point","Seller","Price","Date","IA_Category")];
  test=sample;
  rm(sample,tmp);
  rm(combinations,test1,territory_list);

};

test$Date=as.character(test$Date);
test$Date=as.Date(test$Date,"%d-%m-%Y");
test$price_point=as.character(test$price_point);
test$Territory_1=as.character(test$Territory_1);
test$Category=as.character(test$Category);
test$Sub_category=as.character(test$Sub_category);
test$IA_Category=as.character(test$IA_Category);
test$Price=as.numeric(test$Price);
test11=test[test$Territory_1=="National",];
test12=test[test$Territory_1!="National",];

test1 = (dcast(test,Category+IA_Category+flag+price_point+Date ~ Seller,value.var="Price",sum));
test2 = (test1[,c(6,7,9)]);
test2[test2==0]<-NA;
Median = apply(test2,1,median,na.rm=TRUE);
Median = as.data.frame(Median)
test2[is.na(test2)]=0;
test2$Competitors<-(rowSums(test2>0))
Median=cbind(Median,test2$Competitors)
test2 = cbind(test1,Median)
test2$Diff=(test2$Staples-test2$Median)/(test2$Median)
test2$Diff=100*test2$Diff
names(test2)[11]="Count_competitors"
test2$Count_competitors=as.numeric(test2$Count_competitors)

if (nrow(test12)==0) {
  test12=test11  
};




## Template for server.R script for Plotly/Shiny apps

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {


  output$Box10 = renderUI(selectInput("Territory_1","Select Territory",c(unique(test12[order(test12$Territory_1),]$Territory_1))))
  output$Box1 = renderUI(selectInput("Category","Select Product Category",c(unique(test[which(test$Territory_1 == input$Territory_1),]$Category))))
  output$Box2 = renderUI(selectInput("IA_Category","Select Product Sub Category",c(unique(test[which(test$Category == input$Category),]$IA_Category))))
  output$Box3 = renderUI(radioButtons("flag","Select Actual/Discounted Price",c("Actual","Discounted")))
  output$Box4 = renderUI(dateInput("date","Select Date"))

  ## Subsetting data##

  subdata101 =reactive(test12[which(test12$Territory_1 == input$Territory_1),]);
  subdata102=reactive(unique(rbind(test11,subdata101())));
  subdata1 = reactive(subdata102()[which(subdata102()$Category == input$Category),])
  subdata2 = reactive(subdata1()[which(subdata1()$IA_Category == input$IA_Category),])
  subdata3 = reactive(subdata2()[which(subdata2()$flag == input$flag),])
  subdata4 = reactive(subdata3()[which(subdata3()$Date == input$date),])

  subdata5 = reactive(price_change[which(price_change$date == input$date),])
  subdata6 = reactive(subdata5()[,-9])
  subdata7 = reactive(discount_change[which(discount_change$date == input$date),])
  subdata8 = reactive(subdata7()[,-11])

  output$Box5 = renderUI(selectInput("Category1","Select Product Category",c(unique(test2$Category))))

  output$Box6 = renderUI(
    if (is.null(input$Category) || input$Category == "pick one"){return()
    }else selectInput("price_point1", 
                      "Select Quantity", 
                      c(unique(as.character(sort(as.numeric(test2$price_point[which(test2$Category == input$Category1)]),decreasing = FALSE)))))
  )
  #unique(as.character(sort(as.numeric(test2$price_point[which(test2$Category == input$Category)]),decreasing = FALSE)))
  output$Box7 = renderUI(radioButtons("flag1","Select Actual/Discounted Price",c("Actual","Discounted")))
  output$Box8 = renderUI(dateInput("Date1","Select Date"))





  subdata9 = reactive(test2[which(test2$Category == input$Category1),])
  subdata10 = reactive(subdata9()[which(subdata9()$price_point == input$price_point1),])
  subdata11 = reactive(subdata10()[which(subdata10()$flag == input$flag1),])
  subdata12 = reactive(subdata11()[which(subdata11()$Date == input$Date1),])

  ## ADD DATA
  #YOUR_DATA<- call_your_data_file

  output$trendPlot <- renderGraph({

    xaxislimits=as.character(sort(unique(as.numeric(test$price_point)),decreasing = FALSE))

    p <-  ggplot(data=test, aes(x=price_point, y=Price, fill=Seller))    +
      geom_bar(stat="identity",position=position_dodge(),colour="black")
    +
      theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
            panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),legend.position="bottom")+
      scale_x_discrete(name="Number of Units Sold",limit=xaxislimits)+
      scale_y_continuous(name="Selling Price")
#     
    #}, width = 1200



    ## Create your ggplot
    #YOUR_PLOT <- ggplot(YOUR_DATA, YOUR_GGPLOT_SPECIFICATIONS)

    ## You can edit your graph with ggplot syntax here!

    ## This function rewrites the ggplot figure in Plotly syntax
    ## and returns data information (gg$data) and layout information (gg$layout)
    #gg<- gg2list(YOUR_PLOT)
    gg<- gg2list(p)

    # ggplotly(p)

#     # start comment
#     data <- list()
#     for(i in 1:(length(gg)-1)){data[[i]]<-gg[[i]]}
#     
#     layout <- gg$kwargs$layout
#     # layout <- gg$layout
#     # Remove the existing annotations (the legend label)        
#     layout$annotations <- NULL 
#     
#     # place legend to the right of the plot
#     layout$legend$x <- 100
#     layout$legend$y <- 1
#     return(list(
#       list(
#         id="trendPlot",
#         task="newPlot",
#         data=data,
#         layout=layout
#       )
#     ))      


    ## You can edit your graph with Plotly syntax here!

    # This sends message up to the browser client, which will get fed through to
    # Plotly's javascript graphing library embedded inside the graph
#           return(list(
#               list(
#                   id="trendPlot",
#                   task="newPlot",
#                   data=gg$data,
#                   layout=gg$layout
#               )
#           ))
#     

#     # 3rd type of code
#     
#     # Use Plotly syntax to further edit the plot:
#     gg$layout$annotations <- NULL # Remove the existing annotations (the legend label)
#     gg$layout$annotations <- list()
#     
#     # Add colored text annotations next to the end of each line
#     # More about plotly annotations: https://plot.ly/r/reference/#annotation
#     # Each key that we update is documented in that link above.
#     for(i in 1:(length(gg$data))){ # data is a list of the lines in the graph
#       gg$layout$annotations[[i]] <- list(
#         text = gg$data[[i]]$name,  # The text label of the annotation, e.g. "Canada"
#         font = list(color = gg$data[[i]]$line$color), # Match the font color to the line color
#         showarrow = FALSE, # Don't show the annotation arrow
#         y = gg$data[[i]]$y[[length(gg$data[[i]]$y)]], # set the y position of the annotation to the last point of the line
#         yref = "y1", # the "y" coordinates above are with respect to the yaxis
#         x = 1, # set the x position of the graph to the right hand side of the graph
#         xref = "paper", # the x coordinates are with respect to the "paper", where 1 means the right hand side of the graph and 0 means the left hand side
#         xanchor = "left" # position the x coordinate with respect to the left of the text
#       );
#     }
#     
#     gg$layout$showlegend <- FALSE # remove the legend
#     gg$layout$margin$r <- 170 # increase the size of the right margin to accommodate more room for the annotation labels
#     
#     # Send this message up to the browser client, which will get fed through to
#     # Plotly's javascript graphing library embedded inside the graph
#     return(list(
#       list(
#         id="trendPlot",
#         task="newPlot",
#         data=gg$data,
#         layout=gg$layout
#       )
#     ))

    # 4th try
    g = ggplotly(p)
    print(g)
  })

})
```

I am not able to understand the concept of  gg2list and the list after wards.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: You need to edit to make your example [minimal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610), which will let people work on the problem instead of spending a lot of time sorting through code which is irrelevant to the issue at hand.

Comment: instead of `graphOutput('trendPlot')` use`plotlyOutput("trendplot")`

Comment: @royr2 i have used graphOutput('trendPlot') as this function is defined in the plotlyGraphwidget.R .This script act as an interface between ui.R and server.R

Comment: A minimal example would be helpful here. Is `graphOutput()` a function that you wrote to bind a plotly graph to shiny widgets?

Comment: @royr2  i have used graphOutput() in my ui.R                                   mainPanel(
                                graphOutput('trendPlot')                                                             
                              ) and the same function is defined in the plotlyGraphWidget.R

Comment: @royr2 I think my problem i in the server.R where i am converting my ggplot2 to plotly. I am using gg2list in order to convert ggplot2 to plotly list. Just have a look at the bottom of the server.R. Though i have commented all the approach there while adding the script in the stackoverflow.

Comment: From what I know, `gg2list` is used to convert the ggplot object into an extensive nested list which contains all the data and settings etc used in that plot. You should really be just be using `ggplotly()` or `plot_ly()` directly.

Comment: @royr2 Thanks for the advise. I have tried to use both ggplotly() and plot_ly. But i am unable to get the plot while running the app either in rstudio or on webbrowser! Kindly give a look at the bottom part of my server.R,renderGraph(). As per my understanding there is some problem there but i am unable to resolve it.

Comment: @royr2 I got the graph. I need to change the gg$layout as list with parameters legend = list(
      x = 1,
      y = 1,
      bgcolor = "transparent") . Graph is getting populated but i did not understand the its meaning. It would be a great help if you can share your views on this or any doc have details about it. Now, i have one more problem in the graph. The bars are very thin ,need to zoom them only it becomes visible and intuitive. Need to fix this also.

Comment: you should be using renderPlotly(), not renderGraph()

Comment: Folks I got the plot using plotly, but the biggest pain is that i can not change the width of the bars on my plot. As of now the bars are very thin and does not look good! Any help would be appreciated.